# Pandas and SQL Alchemy: Specify Column Data Types

Tags: oracle, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

**Updated:**

I saw some guidance [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/type_basics.html), but I can't seem to figure out how to specify the column types when I insert data from pandas into Oracle using the code below. One column is a date, for example, but upon importing, it is converted to a string.

Also, if I want the column names to be slightly different in my Oracle database, do I need to first rename the columns via pandas then send them to Oracle via to_sql?

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import cx_Oracle as cx
pwd=input('Enter Password for server:')
engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://schema:'+pwd+'@server:1521/service_name')
df=pd.read_csv(r'path\data.csv',encoding='latin-1',index_col=0)
name='table1'
df.to_sql(name,engine,if_exists='append')
```

Comment: You have to pass a table name, like: `df.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='append')` (actually the code you give should error I think)

Comment: Thanks, @joris . I was supposed to put the service name where I had the table name and then add the table name as you suggested. This worked, so I'm now going to see how to specify field types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please read [SQL Data Types](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-data-types) section of the pandas documentation as well as the [`to_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method.

You are able to specify the data type using `dtype` parameter like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import String, Date, DateTime
df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append', dtype={'mydatecol': DateTime})
```

As to the names of the columns, it is easiest to rename columns in the dataframe before calling `to_sql`:

```
df2 = df.rename(columns={'oldname': 'newname', ...})
```